# List is empty after parsing XML with LinQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml file similar to the following:

```
<doc>
  <file>
    <header>
      <source>
        RNG
      </source>
    </header>
    <body>
      <item name="items.names.id1">
         <property>propertyvalue1</property>
      </item>
      <!-- etc -->
      <item name="items.names.id100">
         <property>propertyvalue100</property>
      </item>
      <!-- etc -->
      <item name="otheritems.names.id100">
         <property>propertyvalue100</property>
      </item>
    </body>
  </file>
</doc>
```

And the following class:

```
private class Item
{
    public string Id;
    public string Property;
}
```

The file has, for example, 100 item entries (labeled 1 to 100 in the name attribute). How can I use Linq Xml to get hold of these nodes and place them a in list of item?

Using Selman22's example, I'm doing the following:

```
var myList = xDoc.Descendants("item")
                 .Where(x => x.Attributes("name").ToString().StartsWith("items.names.id"))
                 .Select(item => new Item
                 {
                     Id = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                     Name = (string)item.Element("property")
                 }).ToList();
```

However, the list is empty. What am I missing here?

Comment: The "XML" you posted is invalid. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LINQ to XML:`

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
var myList = xDoc.Descendants("item").Select(item => new Item {
                                      Id = (string)item.Attribute("name"),
                                      Property = (string)item.Element("property")
                                                              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinqToXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) to directly query the XML, or deserialize it and use LINQ to object. If you choose to deserialize I suggest to start from the schema and generate the classes representing your datamodel with [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you don't have the schema of your xml, even **xsd.exe** can infer one from an example xml file, but you probably need to fine tune the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `XElement root = XElement.Parse("your file name");
var items textSegs =(from item in root.Descendants("item")
       select item).ToList();`
Now iterate over list and store it

Comment: That not the way to go, use LinqToXml all the way.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a way of getting information from xml using Xdocument.

```
string input = "<Your xml>";

Xdocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var data = doc.Descendants("item");
List<Items> itemsList = new List<Items>();

foreach(var item in data)
{
string itemname= item.Element("item").Value;
string property = item.Element("property").Value;
itemsList.Add(new item(itemname, property));
}
```

Comment: Please read up on `XDocument.Parse`. You are looking for `XDocument.Load`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want the code given how your question is phrased.. also I'm assuming the real XML is very simplistic as well.

```
var items = from item in doc.Descendants("item")
            select new Item()
            {
             Id = item.Attributes("name").First().Value,
             Property = item.Elements().First().Value,
            };
```

Just ensure that your xml is loaded into doc. You can load the xml in two ways:

```
// By a string with xml
var doc = XDocument.Parse(aStringWithXml);
// or by loading from uri (file)
var doc = XDocuemnt.Load(aStringWhichIsAFile);
```